# Split DatetimeIndex into date and time MultiIndex conveniently in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series, multi-index

So let's say I have DatetimeIndex:ed data like this (there would be several days of course):

```
                             X      Y       Z
timestamp           
2013-01-02 10:00:13.295000   366    -8242   -1820
2013-01-02 10:00:13.329000   366    -8016   -1820
2013-01-02 10:00:13.352000   32     -8016   -1820
2013-01-02 10:00:13.882000   32     -9250   -1820
2013-01-02 10:00:15.076000  -302    -9250   -1820
```

and I want it MultiIndexed like this:

```
                                 X      Y       Z
Date           Time     
2013-01-02     10:00:13.295000   366    -8242   -1820
               10:00:13.329000   366    -8016   -1820
               10:00:13.352000   32     -8016   -1820
               10:00:13.882000   32     -9250   -1820
               10:00:15.076000  -302    -9250   -1820
```

I know you could (probably) extract the DatetimeIndex, split it with .date() and .time() into two columns and set it as a new index for the Dataframe, but **is there a more 'pandaic' way of doing this?** It would seem to me that this sort of functionality would come handy...

Comment: what is your end goal here? in effect, ``df.resample('D')`` does this, but you almost always want to compute a reduction function

Comment: Basically I would like to go over all the dates in a loop and perform some data analysis at each pass... I want to keep all the data, so resample won't do...

Comment: Well, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing; you don't need to explicity split the days and times, very inefficient that way, and you can alsways ``df.groupby(df.index.date).transform(...)`` as well

Comment: Yeah, I actually knew that already, but I actually wanted also to be able to select the date-grouped data by just a *number* of day instead of 'YYYY-MM-DD' etc... actually the solution below doesn't seem to allow that either. I guess I just need to write up a list of dates as strings and loop over that(?)

Comment: you can groupon df.index.day as well; if you find yourself looping then its the wrong way.

Comment: Wow... thanks Jeff, that's awesome, I wasn't aware of that!! Technically Happy001's answer is already the correct one, but your's is more useful (feel free to write it up as an answer if you want and I'll mark it as the correct one)

Comment: its fine; just trying to help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way I can think of is

```
In [13]: df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.date, df.index.time], names=['Date','Time'])

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
                              X     Y     Z
Date       Time                            
2013-01-02 10:00:13.295000  366 -8242 -1820
           10:00:13.329000  366 -8016 -1820
           10:00:13.352000   32 -8016 -1820
           10:00:13.882000   32 -9250 -1820
           10:00:15.076000 -302 -9250 -1820

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hmm on second thought, now the index looks a bit funny... can't figure out how to conveniently get all data on a given date, so that e.g. df[0] would just give the first day data...

Comment: use `df.ix[datetime.date(2013,1,2)]`. you'll need to sort by index first.

Comment: I guess you mean: df.loc[datetime.date(datetime(2013,1,2))